# How to pass an argument to dc_shell in tcl mode?

Tags: shell, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass an argument to the design compiler shell through my shell script.

```
clk_period=20.30
dc_shell-t -f my_scripts.tcl $clk_period
```

it gives an error

```
 Error: Unexpected argument '20.30'
```

how it is possible to use such a feature? I use it in tcl programming when using tclsh compiler by means of argc and argv. but dc shell does not accept extra arguments

Answer (score 1):

You can also pass in environment variables from the shell and access them with `getenv`:

```
# my_scripts.tcl:
try {
    set clk_period [getenv CLK_PERIOD]
} on error {msg} {
    puts "ERROR: missing CLK_PERIOD environment variable"
    puts "Message: $msg"
    exit 1
}
```

Command:

```bash
CLK_PERIOD="20.30" dc_shell-t -f my_scripts.tcl
```

Answer (score 0):

I just finally discovered a way to do this myself after this came up in my search.  Some tools apparently use -tclargs, but not the case w/ Synopsys.  The -x option allows you to pass in a tcl command.  So something like this works:

```
% dc_shell -f script.tcl -x "set test true"
```

script can echo $test and show true.